# Loop error in R to build tables

Tags: r, loops, dplyr

I'm trying to create 3 dataframes using a loop in R , the code is as below:
Ideally I would like to have a dfmean, dfmedian, dfsum.

```
 list<- c("mean","sum","median")

 for (i in list) {
   df[[i]]<-df%>%
   group_by(Year)%>%
   summarise_if(is.numeric, i , na.rm = TRUE) 
   }
```

I get the following error: 
          Error in `[[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, i, value = list(Year = 1:10,

Comment: You're extracting *from* a frame named `df` and storing *to* a subset of a `list` named `df` ... do you see something wrong here? Perhaps you can use a different variable for storing ...

Comment: @ r2evans , Hi and tks, I did try Tes[[I]] and I got the following error: Error: object 'Tes' not found

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid loop while using `dplyr`. You can simply re-write your `summarise_if` as:

```
library(dplyr)

list<- c("mean","sum","median")

df %>% group_by(Year) %>% 
  summarise_if(is.numeric, .funs = list )

# The below result is from a sample data.frame used by me
#
# # A tibble: 3 x 7
#    Year A_mean B_mean A_sum B_sum A_median B_median
#   <int>  <dbl>  <dbl> <int> <int>    <dbl>    <dbl>
# 1     1   4.71   24.7    33   173     4.00     24.0
# 2     2   8.00   28.0     8    28     8.00     28.0
# 3     3   7.00   27.0    14    54     7.00     27.0
```

**Data:**

```
df <- data.frame(Year = sample(1:3,10,replace = TRUE), A=1:10, B=21:30)
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to first create and empty list and then put the generated data frames in it... it should work if the rest of your code is fine.

```
    list<- c("mean","sum","median")

Test=list()

    for (i in list) {
       Test[[i]]<-df%>%
       group_by(Year)%>%
       summarise_if(is.numeric, i , na.rm = TRUE) 
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

As it appears you're working within `tidyverse`, use `purrr::map` to apply multiple summarization functions:

```
require(tidyverse)

operations <- c("mean", "sum", "median")

dfs <- operations %>%
  map(~ df %>%
        group_by(Year) %>%
        summarise_if(is.numeric, .x, na.rm=TRUE))

> class(dfs)
[1] "list"

> dfs[[1]]
# A tibble: 3 x 3
   Year     a      b
  <int> <dbl>  <dbl>
1  2001 0.250 0.0600
2  2002 0.201 0.0686
3  2004 0.253 0.0222
```

**Data**

```
n <- 100
df <- data.frame(Year=sample(2001:2005, replace = TRUE), 
                 a=rnorm(n), 
                 b=rnorm(n))

> df %>% head()
  Year            a           b
1 2001 -0.002929493 -0.29111621
2 2001  1.590653841 -0.39661866
3 2002  1.041438363 -0.62323955
4 2004  1.854152790 -0.06730789
5 2002  0.396443422  0.66564886
6 2001  0.174203172  0.83243156
```